# Magento 2 minicart, welcome message, other do not work with page cache disabled after customer login

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, javascript

With **Magento 2.0.4** cache, more specifically page **cache enabled**, everything works.

If I disable it, clear cookies, and login as customer than products in **minicart** are not there.

Welcome message does not really work right.
I have to add a product to cart from a product page in order to see the minicart. Than if I go to checkout, country is not displayed in address summary (shipping address already added in my account).

I've done debugging and it looks like the problem is pointing to:
`module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/customer-data.js`.
The cookie `private_content_version` is set in `module-page-cache/view/frontend/web/js/page-cache.js` and used in `customer-data.js`. See `customerData::reload` function.

With page cache disabled, the data is not loaded from the server as the function `dataProvider::getFromServer()` does.

When page cache is disabled the cookie `private_content_version` is not there (page-cache.js is not executed off course). But the cookie `section_data_ids` has only '*' and 'messages' => empty (false or null).

When page cache is enabled there is `private_content_version` and `section_data_ids` has what keys with values:

```
*:      null
cart:       123
compare-products:       123
customer:       123
directory-data:     123
last-ordered-items:     123
multiplewishlist:       123
review:     123
wishlist:       123
```

After I login with page cache enabled, on customer dashboard there are 2 additional ajax requests that load data:

`http://test.localhost/customer/section/load/?sections=&update_section_id=false&_=123
http://test.localhost/customer/section/load/?sections=directory-data&update_section_id=false&_=123`

These contain json objects with customer specific data and directory data like all countries and regions.
With these calls, on checkout the address summary displays the country name.
See: `module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/sections-config.js`
and `module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.js`, function `getCountryName`.

Is this a **Magento 2** bug or it's something that I messed up ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you been able to fix this or find what exactly is causing this? I've got very similar issue, Magento ver. 2.0.1. If I flush the cache (deleting all cache folders) I get similar error message in the browser console: `GET http://example.com/customer/section/load/?sections=&update_section_id=false&_=1462374643065  500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet. In your case it may be a simpler case. See what the error is and try to fix it. Enable errors in Magento 2 and work around that specific error. I don't get errors, it's just that it doesn't load the data. I haven't seen errors in my case.

Comment: I have faced same error and i will say its a magento2 bug as with FPC enabled it will work but once you disable it will not. To fix it temporary you need to refresh minicart programmatically on each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does appear to be an outstanding issue, though perhaps it is resolved in newer versions of M2. See Magento GitHub issues:

- ["No items" in minicart in 2.1](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5377) (open as of this writing)
- [Minicart empty if FPC disabled in Magento 2.1.1](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6882) (open as of this writing)
- [Minicart shows no product even when I have products in cart](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4010) (closed)

As far as what you can try...

If this is cookie-related, you may be able to rule out some possibilities by visiting your site in a private browsing/incognito browser. Go through your workflow (not logged in, add product to cart, customer log in, look at /checkout/cart and minicart dropdown).

Additionally, it may be helpful to review the [M2 dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/) for best practices regarding configuration of the caches in development versus [configuration in production](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/prod/prod.html). In my experience, in development, it is OK to have all caches enabled in development, and simply flush when required (read docs for descriptions of each cache). Note, as a mostly front-end dev, I personally prefer to develop with FPC, Blocks output, and layout caches disabled - this allows frontend changes to be seen more easily.